# Count from 0 to X possible, count from 1 to x gives error 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range' python

Tags: python, count, range

I want to count from 1 to 65 and wright this as a string but i keep receiving the following error

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I use te following code

```
File = []
for i in range(1,65):

    print (i)
    File.append(i)
    File[i] = 'File' + str(i)
```

I know there are simpler ways to do this count but it is necessary that i get the file name so I can wright this to csvfile.

Strange thing is when i use the same code but change (1,65) to (0,64)
It works fine.
So counting from 0 tot 64 gives me no error but it is crucial for my program that i count from 1 to 65.

I have no idea way this is a problem 
It frustrates me that the code is so simpel and that 1 simple change of numbers makes the code behave completely different.

Every suggestions or help is appreciated!

Kind Regards

Comment: Your trying to assign something to element 1 of a list when there is nothing in element 0, so therefore it's out of range.

Comment: `range(1, 65)` is 1, 2, ... 64. When you append `1` to File, it becomes File's first element, `File[0]`

Comment: I knew the solution was something verry simple. Thanks guys you saved me a lot of time! And it makes sense now.

Comment: Also, there's no need to append `i` and overwrite it immediately; You can do directly `File.append('File' + str(i))`. As a side note, avoid using capitalized variable names in Python, the usage is to use them for class names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following adjustment to your code:

```
File = []
for i in range(1,65):

    print (i)
    File.append(i)
    File[i-1] = 'File' + str(i)
```

`File[i]` doesn't exist yet because python indexes from zero.  So, when you append `i` to `File`, the location of `i` is at index `i-1`

---

As an aside, I would use a list comprehension to make this neater:

```
File = ['File{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 65)]
```

Or:

```
File = ['File' + str(i) for i in range(1, 65)]
```

Both produce the same result and don't require indexing.

Comment: Thanks! Such an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because at the very first loop you will be calling an Index that does not exist.

```
#for i == 1
File.append(1)
File[1] = 'File' + str(1) #in here it calls an index that does not exist
```

call File[i-1] instead.

```
for i in range(1,65):

print (i)
File.append(i)
File[i-1] = 'File' + str(i)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the first step the index in the File list should be 0.

This code fix your problem:

```
File = []
for i in range(1, 66):
    print(i)
    File.append(i)
    File[i-1] = 'File' + str(i)
```